# Itext missing line break on chunk

Tags: itext

I'm using Itext to generate a pdf and I need to do something like Chunk.keepOnSameLine.

I'm building a Phrase that can have several lines that are composed by multiple Chunks and when the line ends, I want the chunk not to be broken.

The Chunk is a name and a date. Ex: "John Smith (2016-01-13 11:13)"

The code is like

```
    Phrase p = new Phrase();
    Chunk c1 = new Chunk("FirstName LastName (2016-01-13 11:13)");
    p.Add(c1);
    Chunk c2 = new Chunk("FirstName LastName (2016-01-13 11:13)")
    p.Add(c2);
    Chunk c3 = new Chunk("FirstName LastName (2016-01-13 11:13)")
    p.Add(c3);
    Chunk c4 = new Chunk("FirstName LastName (2016-01-13 11:13)")
    p.Add(c4);
    Chunk c5 = new Chunk("FirstName LastName (2016-01-13 11:13)")
    p.Add(c5);
    Chunk c6 = new Chunk("FirstName LastName (2016-01-13 11:13)")
    p.Add(c6);
    Chunk c7 = new Chunk("FirstName LastName (2016-01-13 11:13)")
    p.Add(c7);
```

(the code is dynamic so I don't know how many chunks will exist.

On the result phrase is showing like

[image: phrasewithbraks]

the resulting phrase is then added to a PdfPCell

Comment: I've seen Itext has a tendency to insert soft hyphen characters when importing text from PDFs. I wonder if the opposite is also true! You could try sticking a soft hypen character at the end of each chunk to see if it changes the break behaviour.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the hyphen is a breaking character...

Comment: Soft hyphen shouldn't be rendered, it's sole purpose is to hint at where to break. Hopefully it should break on the soft hyphen before picking an arbitary point to break.

Comment: But what i intend is that the break should be before the FirstName, never in the middle of the Chunk

Comment: You could try adding a soft hyphen at the end of a chunk :)

Comment: @NeilP *I've seen Itext has a tendency to insert soft hyphen characters when importing text from PDFs* - iText does not insert additional characters during text extraction. If it extracts those characters, they are already present in the PDF.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify how iText splits lines by implementing `ISplitCharacter` and replacing the defaults (hyphen and space) with your own:

```
public class CustomSplitCharacter : ISplitCharacter
{
    public bool IsSplitCharacter(
        int start, int current, int end, char[] cc, PdfChunk[] ck)
    {
        char c = ck == null
            ? cc[current]
            : (char)ck[Math.Min(current, ck.Length - 1)]
                .GetUnicodeEquivalent(cc[current])
        ;
        return (c == ')');
    }
}
```

Then call `SetSplitCharacter()` on `Chunk`:

```
string chunkText = "FirstName LastName (2016-01-13 11:13)";
Random random = new Random();
var font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD); 
using (Document document = new Document())
{
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
    document.Open();
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        var asterisk = new String('*', random.Next(1, 20));
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(
            string.Format("[{0}] {1}", asterisk, chunkText), 
            font
        );
        chunk.SetSplitCharacter(new CustomSplitCharacter());
        phrase.Add(chunk);
    }

    document.Add(phrase);
}
```

This assumes your `Chunk` ends with `)` like your example code, or that you have control of the `Chunk`'s last character of text.

No dependency on a specific font. :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Unicode `U+00A0` which is a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). You'll also want to use `U+2011` which is a [non-breaking hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Nonbreaking_hyphens). However, a non-breaking hyphen is technically a different character than a regular hyphen so you'll need a font that supports it, too.

```
var testString = "FirstName LastName (2016-01-13 11:13)";
var nbsp = "\u00a0";
var nbhy = "\u2011";

//With a normal space
var p1 = new Phrase();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    p1.Add(new Chunk(testString + " "));
}
doc.Add(p1);


//Create a font that supports our "hard hyphen"
var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontFile, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
var f = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 12);
testString = testString.Replace(" ", nbsp).Replace("-", nbhy);

//With a non-breaking space
var p2 = new Phrase();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    p2.Add(new Chunk(testString + " ", f));
}
doc.Add(p2);
```

Comment: I've already undestand the problem of the non-breaking hyphen, but I put it and didn't work. No I understand because of the FONT issue. No I have a question that all my fonts are declared as `font_bigBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18, Font.BOLD);` What is the `fontFile` used on the `CreateFont` ?

Comment: The PDF spec declares 4 text fonts and 1 symbol font (14 total when counting variants) that all conformers (like iText and Adobe Reader) must be "aware" of and `FontFamily.HELVETICA` is one of them. These core text fonts support the 7-bit ASCII standard but it gets a little grey in the 8-bit section. Essentially, if you don't specify a font of your own you'll be relying on fonts from the early 90's (or 80's if they came over from PostScript).